# Why is this elif statement throwing an error?

Tags: python

```
class TheBridge(Scene):

def enter(self):
    print "You burst into the bridge with the bomb"
    print "There are a number of gothons standing about"
    print "and looking scared of the bomb you currently have underneath your arm"
    print "They look nervous about what you are going to do"

    action = raw_input("> ")


    if action == "Throw the bomb":
        print "You throw the bomb at the gorcons on the bridge"
        print "They pure and utter crap themselves and pull out their laser blasters and shhot you dead"
        print "at least the bomb will kill the gorcons, you die a hero"
        return 'death'

    elif action == "Put the bomb down slowly":
        print "You pull you laser blaster from your holster and point it at the bomb"
        print " You very slowly set the bomb on the ground and move backwards"
        print "You then jump back through the door and start firing your gun at the"
        print "lock and you blast it so the gorcons can't escape"
        print "You then procede to try and find an escape pod"
        return 'escape_pod'

    else:    
        print "DOES NOT COMPUTE"
        return "the_bridge"
```

It's throwing a syntax error for some reason. Maybe I'm a complete idiot and can't see something blindingly obvious. Definitely not the spacing or indentation or anything like that as I have checked that.

Any ideas?

Error Message:

```
  File "ex43.py", line 131
    elif action == "Put the bomb down slowly":
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
```

Comment: Please show the surrounding code, including the preceding `if` statement.

Comment: Also show the error message so we can help you decipher it. Python error messages are very informative, you should learn to read them.

Comment: " Definitely not the spacing or indentation or anything like that as I have checked that." I would check the indentation of `def enter(self)`

Comment: @YuppieNetworking sorry it pasted in weird, in the code it is tabbed in fine. Fixing that now.

Comment: Check you're not mixing tabs and spaces, too.

Comment: Ok it's working now. I just retyped it all making sure i was using tabs and it seems to be working even though it seemed fine. Cheers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are mixing tabs and spaces (your copied post here certainly does).

Run your code with `python -tt` and fix any problems that finds.

Preferably, replace all tabs with spaces and configure your editor to do so automatically.